# local fakes3 and capistrano - authentication error

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, capistrano

In my ruby on rails app, I am currently testing the functions that update my application's 'library'. It's built to work with capistrano and s3, and the previous team got their setup working in the production environment.

As a new member on the team, I'm figuring out about the application, and wish to test their setup locally. fakes3 seemed the ideal solution to faking an s3 service. The application runs on a linux system.

However, when I try to execute any of the commands, like `cap fakes3 deploy:setup`, it gives me the following message:

```
triggering load callbacks
  * 2016-01-12 08:19:43 08:19:43 == Currently executing `rbenv:setup_default_environment'
  * executing "echo \"$HOME/.rbenv\""
    servers: ["127.0.0.1"]
connection failed for: 127.0.0.1 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@127.0.0.1)
```

for user ubuntu, I have made an account and I can login to the server via ssh. Whenever I try a cap command, my auth.log file throws this line:

```
Jan 12 08:19:43 ubuntu sshd[2296]: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1 [preauth]
```

I'm not sure what this means, but it seems a vital error. Any comment on this line is appreciated.

**Here are the things I have done so far**:

In my hosts file I've added the line: `127.0.0.1 local.s3.endpoint local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint`

I have executed the command `fakes3 -r /mnt/fakes3_root -p 1234` and this service is up and running:

```
Loading FakeS3 with /mnt/fakes3_root on port 1234 with hostname s3.amazonaws.com
[2016-01-12 08:18:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-01-12 08:18:54] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-01-12 08:18:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1944 port=1234
localhost - - [12/Jan/2016:08:19:18 CET] "PUT /local-bucket HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /local-bucket
```

and in my rails console I have executed the following:

```
s3=AWS::S3.new(
  :access_key_id => '',
  :secret_access_key => '',
  :s3_endpoint       => 'local.s3.endpoint',
  :s3_port           => 1234,
  :use_ssl           => false,
  :s3_force_path_style => true
)
s3.buckets.create('local-bucket')
```

finally, in my projects deploy.yml I've added the s3 settings as followed:

```
s3:
  storage: filesystem
  path: /ec2-dev/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
  s3_credentials:
    access_key_id: "anything"
    secret_access_key: "anything"
  bucket: "local-bucket"
  s3_host_name: "local.s3.endpoint"
  # default_host: "local.s3.endpoint"
  url: ":s3_alias_url"
  s3_host_alias: "local-bucket.local.s3.endpoint:1234"
  s3_options:
    use_ssl: false
    s3_port: 1234
  creds: i3
```

I've also tried setting these as this, because these settings are more in line with the normal s3 settings:

```
 s3:
   storage: filesystem
   bucket: local-bucket
   upload_bucket: local-bucket
   region: eu-west-1
   path: /ec2-dev/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename
   url: :s3_alias_url
   creds: i3
```

Needless to say these settings made little to no difference.

To recap: I've made all these settings and I can't connect to my fakes3 bucket, or so it seems. (`connection failed for: 127.0.0.1 (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user ubuntu@127.0.0.1)`) I'm looking for a solution or an alternative to test s3 locally. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Nobody knows anything about this?